# Why am i not able to link my C/C++ libraries with NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, cygwin, environment-variables, libraries

I've downloaded **C/C++ libraries** from **[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)**, and set the environment variables according to the instructions [here](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html), in NetBeans.

I've also gone through [this](http://www.netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html).

Actually I followed the same steps on a different machine and everything worked out fine.
But on my machine the associations aren't made.
for example: `#include<stdio.h>` says `No such file or directory`.

**Any idea what the problem might be?**

The Cygwin package I downloaded is also fine, I downloaded it twice.

Answer (score 1):

If it's complaining about a #include, that's a compile issue, not a linking issue.

What happens if you create a new C/C++ application project and try to build it?

In the Build node of the project properties, is the correct Tool Collection selected? (Cygwin in your case).  And the Tools -> Options, on the C/C++ tab, is that tool collection set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you have a file `c:\cygwin\usr\include\stdio.h`.